# Is delphi XE7 compatible with windows 10?

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-xe7

Anybody know if delphi xe7 compatible with windows 10?
Embarcadero says that XE8 is compatible. But tells nothing about XE7.

Comment: to build universal apps now you probably need ms tools

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can install XE7 on Windows 10, and the executables that it produces are compatible with Windows 10.

Embarcadero have been producing a lot of marketing recently that implies that you need XE8 to do Windows 10 development. Truth be told, you can use any version of Delphi beyond Delphi 1. Of course the newer versions make life easier, and clearly you need XE2 or later to target 64 bit executables.

So far as I can see, the only Windows 10 specific feature that is offered with XE8 is a Windows 10 style. That was what I took from a conversation with Marco Cantú on the subject. I guess that would be useful for FMX targets. If you are targeting classic VCL apps, and use the standard system theme, then this is of no interest. There's no point at all in faking the system style when you can let the system give you the true style. My old Delphi 6 applications, built with Mike Lischke's theme manager code, look and feel on Windows 10 identical to an application built with XE8.

Comment: Actually there is another Win10 specific feature available for XE8 that can be installed via GetIt: Windows 10 WinRT support. As I don't have installed Win10 yet, I cannot say what advantage this might have.

Comment: @Uwe Delphi can't produce WinRT executables

Comment: I didn't say that. But I found this one: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2015-june-windows10-notifications-vcl-winrt.html

Comment: @Uwe I wouldn't call that WinRT support.

Comment: Perhaps a bad wording of mine. The correct description is "Object Pascal Interfaces for Windows 10 WinRT access". But no matter what we call it - it is a Windows 10 specific feature available in XE8 and not in XE7 (at least not unless you own XE8).

Comment: In Windows 10, Microsoft is exposing COM wrappers for WinRT APIs, and Embarcadero is publishing components on GetIt that wrap those COM wrappers for drop-in to Delphi/C++ apps.

Comment: @Uwe It's easy enough to get access to that from older Delphi versions. Emba are just trying to get people to upgrade with misleading marketing.

Comment: Hmmm... Not misleading at all. Just like, in the olden days, the VCL made accessing and using the Windows API a lot easier, this seems to make using WinRT easier. I would call that "support" alright.

Comment: @Rudy It misled me. Marco made a statement  that Delphi apps wouldn't look truly native on Win 10 unless they were built with XE8.

Answer (score 2):

Although Embarcadero says that XE8 is compatible with Windows 10, I'm unable to install or load our existing bpl projects using XE8 with Windows 10.
I moved to XE8 because our projects wouldn't build with Windows 10 using XE4.

Comment: What do you mean by 'wouldn't build'? Maybe it is a pascal code problem and not a Win10 compatibility problem.

Comment: Every bpl fails to link (Link error LME288). They are C++ bpls, though since it's a linker error, there's a possibility that the problem may also affect the linkage of Delphi code. It is not a random error, it happens consistently every time. I've had to move back to Windows 7 to build my bpl projects.

Comment: @AussieDev I have exactly the same issues, it was fine on Windows 8.1, but moving to 10 has given me these LME288 errors. I don't have it consistently every time, but most times. Compatibility mode doesn't fix it. One thing interesting was installing XE7 on a Windows 10 laptop freshly, that had not had it installed before, seems to work, apart from a random stringstream to integer conversion fails, that clearly should not fail. I don't really trust a build made on Windows 10 with XE7.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and run Delphi XE7 on a Windows 10 machine. And of course you can compile your projects on Windows 10.
But there were no enhancements made in the VCL or FireMonkey towards the new operating system. There is no *official support* for Windows 10. Your applications may not look and feel 100% like other applications do on Windows 10. But they can still be run as long as long as they don't use any old API that is no longer supported on Windows 10.

Comment: "But there were no enhancements made in the VCL or FireMonkey towards the new operating system" -Yes, of course.

Comment: Why would the applications not look and feel like other Windows 10 applications? I see no reason for that to be the case. That sounds a little like the FUD that has been emanting from Embarcadero recently.

Comment: Good question. Maybe (Wosi wanted to say) there is some kind of manifest file that needs to be included in the EXE to make them look like Win10 - like the manifest file required by Delphi 7 to make the apps use WinXP themes.

Comment: As far as I know FireMonkey paints the UI itself on each system. It tries to imitate the original system UI as good as it can. When FireMonkey for XE7 was made there was no Windows 10 to be imitated.

And there can be also some new API which is not covered by XE7 VCL. I read anywhere about an issue where the close button of a window doesn't  turn red when hovered by the mouse cursor. I'm not sure whether this is a VCL problem or not. But I can imagine there can be some other small details which don't work perfectly.

Comment: @Wosi Certainly for FMX that is the case. You need a Windows 10 style for that. For VCL, nothing is needed. You are good to go with any version of Delphi released in the past 10 years. As for APIs not covered by XE7, well, the new Windows 10 APIs aren't wrapped by XE8 either. As for the red close button, nobody could repro that with any version of Delphi. As for other details not working, what are they? It's just as plausible that there are bugs in XE8 that are not present in XE7.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and run Delphi XE7 on a Windows 10 machine.